# Script to find particular value from one file and replace it in another file

Tags: regex, perl, shell, sed, tcl

I have two data files, *ABC* and *XYZ*:

Partial contents of ABC:

```
cancsi(64): 10-s01: (c) Copyright 1995-2014 
cancsi> source ncancsi
cancsi>  set dump_shm  on
on

*Ve3* Loading libsscore.so
*Ve3* : Parallel Dumping.

// X_deb:  step # : 9  
// X_deb:  in  : 4'b0000  
// X_deb: out : 4'b1110  
// X_deb: load (4 , 4'b1010) ; 
// X_deb: MK : 4'b1111  

// X_deb:  step # : 10  
// X_deb:  in  : 4'b0100  
// X_deb: out : 4'b1001  
// X_deb: load (4 , 4'b1100) ;

// X_deb:  step # : 11  
// X_deb:  in  : 4'b0001  
// X_deb: out : 4'b1100  
// X_deb: load (4 , 4'b1011) ;  
// X_deb: MK : 4'b1110
```

Contents of file XYZ:

```
    This is output file..
    Run 5
    "Random text"
    X_step_9 4 4'b1010 ( 4'b1110)   
    X_step_10 4 4'b1100 (4'b1001)   
    X_step_11 4'b1011 (4'b1100)
```

---

Expected output of XYZ:

```
   This is output file..
    Run 5
    "Random text"
    X_step_9 4 4'b1010 ( 4'bxxx0)   
    X_step_10 4 4'b1100 (4'b1001)   
    X_step_11 4'b1011 (4'bxxx0)
```

---

Expected Format syntax of file *XYZ*:
    X_step_#  (Extract value of "out" but if *MK* is present for the step then wherever bit "1" is there for that "MK" value, script should replace the same bit of "out" with "x" and replace it and wherever "0" is there for "MK" value "out" should remain same).

The script I was using was having some issues, it was unable to *grep* an *MK* value for the step and put it in *XYZ* file, instead of that the script was putting "out" value for all the steps.
Unfortunately I deleted that script. 
NOTE: in *ABC* file, not all steps have an *MK* value.  (In the above example only step 9 and 11 have an *MK* value).

Now I need to create one generic script (in any language) for all the steps (there are many steps, not only 9,10,11) which can do the following things:

- it will `grep` *MK* value for particular step from *ABC* file.
- after that it will `grep` for that step in *XYZ* file (X_step_#) and if *MK* is present for the step then wherever bit "1" is there for that "MK" value, script should replace the same bit of "out" with "x" and replace it and wherever "0" is there for "MK" value "out" should remain same.

For example: Script will find *MK* value for step 9 from *ABC* and then it will search for X_step_9 in *XYZ* file and then it will find place of  all *1's* bits from *MK* value and then it will replace "out" value with *"x"* whenever *1's" bit are present in *MK* value, if *0's* are there then it will not make any change for that place in "out" value. 
Ex:

Input:

```
// X_deb:  step # : 11  
// X_deb:  in  : 4'b0001  
// X_deb: out : **4'b1100**  
// X_deb: load (4 , 4'b1011) ;  
// X_deb: MK : 4'b1110
```

Output:

```
X_step_11 4'b1011 (4'bxxx0)
```

- It will replace bits of "out" with x's wherever "1" is present in the same place for *MK*.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question.

Comment: If it's critical and urgent, then it sounds a lot like you need to employ someone to do it. Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for tech support.

Comment: but please help me here as I cant employ someone for this task.

Comment: You don't get to tell me that something is "very very critical and urgent" unless you are paying me :-) And I don't think I'd take on a paying client who is as bad at describing the problem as you are!

Comment: changed subject

Comment: What tools do you intend to use? Making a frankenprogram out of Perl, Shell, Sed and Tcl is _possible_ but likely a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Tcl solution) You might try something like this, if I understand your specification correctly:

```
proc // args {
    global step data
    set args [lassign $args _ kword]
    set val [lindex $args end]
    switch -- $kword {
        step {
            set step $val 
        }
        MK {
            dict set data $step MK $val
        }
    }
}

proc make_XYZ {in out data} {
    while {[gets $in line] >= 0} {
        if {[regexp {^\s*X_step_(\d+)} $line -> n] && [dict exists $data $n MK]} {
            regsub {\(.*\)} $line ([dict get $data $n MK]) line
        }
        puts $out $line
    }
}

rename unknown _unknown
proc unknown args {}
set data {}
source ABC
rename unknown {}
rename _unknown unknown
file rename -force XYZ XYZ.bak
set f1 [open XYZ.bak r]
set f2 [open XYZ w]
make_XYZ $f1 $f2 $data
close $f1
close $f2
```

Documentation:
[&& (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm),
[rename](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/rename.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[source](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm),
[switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm),
[unknown](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unknown.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: Note that Peter's solution is in Tcl, in case it's not obvious :-)

Comment: and can you please tell how to use this script on unix terminal?

Comment: @Nishant: I haven't worked with Unix for 20 years, but you should be able to start a Tcl shell (e.g. `tclsh` and run the script in that).

Comment: ok thanks. I will try it.
and ABC and XYZ I need to give as input and "any name" as output?

Comment: @Nishant: you will have to provide the actual file names that ABC and XYZ stand for, or an alternative name if you don't want to clobber the XYZ file.

Comment: @peter,
My original ABC file has few text at beginning and because of that I am getting sourcing error.Is there any other way to source ABC file?

Initial contents of ABC:

cancsi(64): 10-s01: (c) Copyright 1995-2014 
cancsi> source ncancsi
cancsi>  set dump_shm  on
on
// X_deb: step # : 9 
// X_deb: in : 4'b0000 
// X_deb: out : 4'b1110 
// X_deb: load (4 , 4'b1010) 
// X_deb: MK : 4'b1111  

I forgot to mention in my question.
all lines with has X_* starting with // 
sorry for that, but I guess it will not create issue.
And this ABC file is basically log file of cancsi tool

Comment: @peter:
when I am adding // in front of these lines.
I am getting below error:
   while executing
"// X_deb: step # : 9"
    (file "ABC" line 1)
    invoked from within
"source ABC"
    (file "peter_script" line 33)
please help me Peter from this.
thanks in advance

Comment: @PeterLewerin after adding those "unknown" related commands in my file. I am not getting errors now. But issue is output file(XYZ) is empty now. Please help

Comment: @PeterLewerin , sorry. Again I forgot to add one thing in the question.
I forgot to add semi column after each  "// X_deb: load" line previously.
I have updated the question accordingly. But I feel it will not create issue? or will it? please help.. sorry for keep asking you questions again and again. This task is very urgent and critical for me.

Comment: @Nishant: no, the semicolons won't cause any problems. Are you getting the desired output now, or are you still having problems?

Comment: @PeterLewerin: yes. I am not getting any issues now. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.  But I have one query.. this script is overwriting current output file. But not replacing out value with MK.. again sorry, I have updated output file in the question. This is last edit. Sorry for this.. I am using this for the first time so this kind of mistakes are occurring.. but I am sure this is last question edit. Please help

Comment: @PeterLewerin : just now updated question again for the last time..sorry for multiple iterations. This is last edit for sure... I just need to replace value of out with MK.(for the steps which is having MK).. everything else should be remain same. Thanks in advance... and apologizes for asking you so many questions again and again.. Please don't mind.

Comment: @Nishant: AFAICT you're getting just that. For #9 and #11 you are getting the MK value (1111 and 1110), and for #10 you are getting the out value (1001), since there is no MK value.

Comment: Is it not possible to just replace MK value from XYZ file and keep other text as it is? Without overwriting the file? @PeterLewerin

Comment: @Nishant: sure, it can be done. I'd have to have a look at it tomorrow though, it's very late here.

Comment: @PeterLewerin. It is working completely fine now.
It is very helpful. Thanks a lot for your help and time. Its really great.. really appreciate your help.  :)

Comment: @PeterLewerin : sorry to disturb you again.
I have one more question. 
Actually problem statement got changed now. 
At output side in last bracket value is of "out" only, but wherever bit "1" is there for that "MK", script should convert the same bit of "out" with "x" value. I have updated the question as well. again sorry, but please help me one last time. i would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Nishant: sorry, I have to draw the line somewhere. I kept working on this answer even though according to Stackoverflow guidelines I shouldn't have, and right now I fear that I will have to keep working on it for some time (have you noticed how many times you have used the word "last" in these comments?). You really need to read the guidelines for asking questions and think about your own responsibilities in finding a solution. With the information you have been given here, you should have no problem solving this "last" hurdle yourself.